# how to compare table width to page size in telerik reporting?

Tags: telerik, width, reporting

I just want to be my paper size in Telerik reporting to be dynamic, so I want to know how to compare the table width to paper size? Also dynamic table column width. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

The table will retain its designed width, unless it has column groups - in this case it will grow horizontally, generating more pages. The table itself can be resized at runtime using Bindings, but this approach will resize all the columns proportionally. Another approach is to modify the report definition prior to rendering, as explained [here](https://www.telerik.com/forums/dynamic-tables-with-dynamic-columns).

Having a dynamically resized pages in a report is not a common requirement - please, try to explain your scenario in details for a more precise answer.